# The problem with very simple file reading using ifstream

Tags: ifstream

Trying reading the file with values using ifstream I get zero value independently on value in file.

Hello!

I'm trying a small test program:

```
#include<fstream>
int main(int npar, char** vpar) {
   std::ifstream parfile(vpar[1]);
   if (parfile.fail()) {
      printf("Problem opening file %s\n",vpar[1]);
      return 1;
   }
   double skippar;
   parfile>>skippar;
   printf("skippar=%d\n",skippar);
   parfile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Compiling it:

```
g++ -o testfparread_simple testfparread_simple.cc
```

Applying it to file test.dat, which contains:

```
[shtol@l3-1-shtol-new testc]$ cat test.dat
2.5
1 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0
```

```
[shtol@l3-1-shtol-new testc]$ testfparread_simple test.dat 
skippar=0
```

Why it returns 0, if in file there is 2.5? I always read files using ifstream but this is the first case of such error for me.

Comment: double requires a %f not %d, anyway use cout

Answer (score 0):

this is a perfect example of why you should use cout . this

```
double skippar;
parfile>>skippar;
printf("skippar=%d\n",skippar);
```

needs to be

```
double skippar;
parfile>>skippar;
printf("skippar=%f\n",skippar);
```

but ideally is would be

```
double skippar;
parfile>>skippar;
std::cout << "skippar=", << skippar << "\n";
```